# How to overlay a mouse pointer on the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, mouse, overlay, android-tv

I'm developing an app for Android Tv. I would create a mouse pointer (moved by the remote) to interact with the UI's activity.

What is the best way to obtain the desired result?
I searched on Google and I found only solutions with the creation of a service, but I don't think is the best way in this case.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I think there are ways that you can use Android's internal pointer, but I don't know how exactly it can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to draw an overlay cursor. The overlay is a special kind of window, that can be made to appear on top of all other. By adding mouse cursor image, you would get a mouse cursor without using real mouse. Check this [page](http://www.pocketmagic.net/android-overlay-cursor/#.UckAcZwxSd4), to know what code you need to use or place in your program. It will also give you more idea and demo.

Comment: but how to do the click action on view above which the mouse overlay is floating